# Chrome Extension - chrome.tabs.group function error ... 'tabIds': Value did not match any choice

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I get error when some tabs are created and I want to group them. Although
See the // Error part below

```
....
    var ids = [];
    myconfig.tabs.forEach((tab) => {
      chrome.tabs.create({ url: tab }).then((tt) => {
        ids.push(tt.id);
      });
    });

... // ids:Array - 0: 72, 1: 73 length: 2

  chrome.tabs.group({tabIds:ids}).then((groupId) => { // ERROR : Error handling response: TypeError: Error in invocation of tabs.group(object options, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'options': Error at property 'tabIds': Value did not match any choice.
      gId = groupId;
    });
  }
});
```

Pls correct me to solve this error, thanks in advance.

Csaba

Comment: `chrome.tabs.group({tabIds:ids})` by this point `ids` doesn't have any values in it yet since `ids` is populated asynchronously when your Promises created in your forEach loop resolve

Comment: So. although the debugging shows 2 number in the ids array, in the real process its empty (because the async funtion in still not finished yet) ?

Comment: Yeah that's right, you can do `console.log(JSON.stringify(ids))` right above `chrome.tabs.group({tabIds:ids}).then(...)` to see what `ids` really holds at the time of logging it.